# Delete allocated memory after moving the pointer to to other place

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory-leaks

I am doing removing element of a binary tree, and it reduces to the following problem:

```
A* a = new A(); // memory allocated to a
A* b = new A();
a = b; // now a and b points to both same memory
```

How do I free the initial memory of a?

This is my code in removing element val in a BST. Is it having memory leaking problem, especially in the case of one child only?

```
Node* remove_helper(Node* n , int value)
{
    if (n == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (value < n->value)
        n->left = remove_helper(n->left, value);
    else if (value > n->value)
        n->right = remove_helper(n->right, value);
    else {
        if (n->left == NULL && n->right == NULL) {
            delete n;
            return NULL;
        }

        if (n->left == NULL) {
            return n->right;
        }
        else if (n->right == NULL) {
            return n->left;
        }
        else {
            Node* tmp = n;
            n = rightMostChild(n->left);
            n->left = rightMostDelete(tmp->left);
            n->right = tmp->right;
        }
    }
    return n;
};
```

Answer (score 9):

You have to free `a` before you assign `b` to it.

```
A* a = new A(); // memory allocated to a
A* b = new A();
delete a;
a = b; // now a and b points to both same memory
```

Or, since you're using `C++`, use a [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

```
auto a = std::make_shared<A>();
auto b = std::make_shared<A>();
a = b; // the original instance of `A` pointed to by `a` will be deleted
       // when b is assigned.
```